# Pagespeed GZIP facebook like button

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, page-speed

I am using mod-deflate on httpd to compress resources.
Pagespeed complains that an external resource (facebook like button) is not being compresssed:

```
Compressing https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yU/r/lvRlebSUWb1.js could save 126.0KiB (69% reduction).
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Not really.

Well, I guess you could ask Facebook and Akamai to compress the object, but good luck with that.

Alternately, you could "solve" this by removing that vile Facebook like button from your webpage, but I suspect you don't want to do that, leaving us with the following:

It is the nature of external resources to be external - they are beyond your control by the very nature of what they are.

Comment: Seems like a huge waste! 126KiB for every fb like button?

Comment: @DD. Well, Faacebook, and by extension, their Like buttons, suck.  Nature of the beast.  At least it's not your bandwidth they're wasting, it's Akamai's, and they pay a sizable chunk for the privilege.

Comment: @DD. "Other people's content is not your responsibility." :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use your own smaller static buttons instead. For example, http://simplesharingbuttons.com/. I haven't used them, but the idea seems very good.